# Pandas quickest way to count concurrences of strings in rows (words in sentences)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, optimization, counter

Imagine that a column of a dataframe contains sentences (words separated by comma) and then I have combination of words (also words separated by comma). **Words are never repeated nor in the sentences nor in the combinations.** I need to count the number of sentences where each combination of word happen, order independent.

I have a column of pandas dataframe, that looks like this:

df.sentences =

```py
0                         GO:0002576,GO:0008150,GO:0043312
1        GO:0001869,GO:0002576,GO:0007597,GO:0010466,GO...
2        GO:0006400,GO:0006412,GO:0006418,GO:0006419,GO...
3        GO:0007416,GO:0030036,GO:0030097,GO:0032092,GO...
4        GO:0002407,GO:0006816,GO:0006874,GO:0006887,GO...
                               ...                        
14503          GO:0002221,GO:0002223,GO:0002376,GO:0045087
14504                                GO:0003351,GO:0048240
14505    GO:0001889,GO:0006351,GO:0006355,GO:0006357,GO...
14506    GO:0006892,GO:0007596,GO:0008089,GO:0016081,GO...
14507    GO:0000209,GO:0007030,GO:0008283,GO:0016567,GO...
Name: annots, Length: 14508, dtype: object
```

and then a list of different combination of strings derived from the above column:
combinations =

```py
0                                                  GO:0007165
1                                                  GO:0007186
2                                                  GO:0007155
3                                                  GO:0006954
4                                                  GO:0019221
                                  ...                        
16778101    GO:0000165,GO:0000209,GO:0002223,GO:0006521,GO...
16778102    GO:0000165,GO:0000209,GO:0002223,GO:0002479,GO...
16778103    GO:0000165,GO:0000209,GO:0002223,GO:0002479,GO...
16778104    GO:0000165,GO:0000209,GO:0002223,GO:0002479,GO...
16778105    GO:0000165,GO:0000209,GO:0002223,GO:0002479,GO...
Name: itemsets, Length: 16778106, dtype: object
```

What I have by now:

```py
setsentences = [set(sentece.split(',')) for sentence in df.sentences]
combinations = [set(comb.split(',')) for comb in combinations]

sentenceCount = {}
for comb in combinations:
    sentenceCount[','.join(comb)] = sum([comb.issubset(sentence) for sentence in setsentences])
```

The problem here (IMO) is a loop of 16778105 iterations... Is there a way to use apply or map over the pandas DF or in the comb to count the sentences quickier ? Maybe tranforming the words to numbers ? Using regex ?

I hope I have explained myself sufficiently. Thanks for your time in advanced.

In order to create an example for testing:

```py
import random,string

chars = string.ascii_uppercase + string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
nsentences = 18000
sentences = [','.join(random.sample(chars, random.randint(1,len(chars)))) for sentence in range(nsentences)]

ncombinations = 1000000
combinations = [','.join(random.sample(chars, random.randint(1,len(chars)))) for sentence in range(ncombinations)]

setsentences = [set(sentence.split(',')) for sentence in sentences]
combinations = [set(comb.split(',')) for comb in combinations]

sentenceCount = {}
for comb in combinations:
    sentenceCount[','.join(comb)] = sum([comb.issubset(sentence) for sentence in setsentences])
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? With the outcome expected?

Comment: Added a code chunk in order to create an example.  The expected output is just a dictionary with {'combination' : nsenteces}. Also I have clarified that words are not repeated in sentences nor in combinations.

Comment: One minor point that should lead to a significant speed increase: Replace `sentenceCount[comb] = sum(map(lambda x : set(comb.split(',')).issubset(x), setsentences))` with `comb_set = set(comb.split(',')); sentenceCount[comb] = sum(map(lambda x: comb_set.issubset(x), setsentences))`. In your version every call of the lambda function does the set building again.

Comment: I have thought a bit about your question and tried some stuff on the weekend but couldn't come up with a really good idea (but I'm not the brightest bulb). It's really hard if there's no additional structure/logic in the data that can be exploited. Another minor point: You can shave of like 10% of the runtime by using a comprehension instead of `map` (`... = sum(comb_set.issubset(x) for x in setsentences)`. Have you thought about a multiprocessing approach? That might actually be helpful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time @Timus , I will use the comprehension instead of the map. Multiprocessing might actually helps my case, but still can't implement since I am using flask and gevent workers which are incompatible with multiprocessing but my next step is to avoid using gevent during this processing. Thanks again

Comment: Perhaps there is something in the structure that can be exploited?  How many total unique words are in the combinations?  What is the maximal length within the combinations?  And how did you develop `combinations`?  Is it all possible combinations of some length of unique words within `sentences` or something else?

Comment: How many total unique words are in the combinations?  - it is highly variable, it depends on the user selection... What is the maximal length within the combinations? - There is not a maximal length, in fact if the user select two collections of words it just grows "exponentially"... And how did you develop combinations? - it is developed using the fpgrowth algorithm so combination depends on the transactions, here referred as sentences